# SAP ABAP: ignore namespaces when reading an XML-Document

Tags: xml, abap

Following problem: I've got an XML-Document which I shall read with SAP ABAP.
Looks like this:

```
<n0: someName >
<n0: someOtherName >
   <n1: underName />
      <n16: underUnderStuff />
</n0: someName>
</n0: someOtherName>
```

So the problem seems to be the n0, n1 etc. I've deleted them for testing and it worked. When using  find_note in ABAP the program can only read the first line. When searching for e.g. the second one it wont't work.
Does anyone has any idea how to ignore the n0 etc. ? Snippets pls.

Comment: How Do you Do it without nameapaces?

Comment: < someName >
< someOtherName >
   < underName />
      < underUnderStuff />
</ someName>
</ someOtherName>

Comment: You have forgotten to share your code.

Comment: Uhm, abap please...

Comment: Namespaces should not be a problem. Post complete xml, including the root node and header lines. This is probably an X/Y question.

Comment: There are many ways to do what you're looking for, so please provide the code so that people can help you efficiently. For more information about participating, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I think that you have tried with the method `FIND_NODE` of `CL_XML_DOCUMENT` but you didn't mention it, and the code   you have done is necessary to explain you what is wrong and how to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath functionality in ABAP for finding elements by name, value, etc with CL_XSLT_PROCESSOR.

```
REPORT zmky_xml_localname.

DATA: lv_string     TYPE string,
      lv_xstring    TYPE xstring,
      lv_document   TYPE REF TO if_ixml_document,
      lo_processor  TYPE REF TO cl_xslt_processor,
      lo_nodes      TYPE REF TO if_ixml_node_collection,
      lo_node       TYPE REF TO if_ixml_node,
      lv_i          TYPE i.

CONCATENATE
  '<n0:someName xmlns:ns0="http://ns0">'
  '<n0:someOtherName>'
     '<n1:underName  xmlns:ns0="http://ns1"/>'
        '<n16:underUnderStuff xmlns:ns0="http://ns16">underUnderStuffValue</n16:underUnderStuff>'
  '</n0:someName>'
  '</n0:someOtherName>'
INTO lv_string.

lv_xstring = cl_proxy_service=>cstring2xstring( lv_string ).

CALL FUNCTION 'SDIXML_XML_TO_DOM'
  EXPORTING
    xml           = lv_xstring
  IMPORTING
    document      = lv_document
  EXCEPTIONS
    invalid_input = 1
    OTHERS        = 2.

CREATE OBJECT lo_processor.
lo_processor->set_source_node( node = lv_document ).
lo_processor->set_expression( expression = '//*[local-name()="underUnderStuff"]' ).
lo_processor->run( progname = space ).
lo_nodes = lo_processor->get_nodes( ).
CHECK lo_nodes IS NOT INITIAL.
lv_i = lo_nodes->get_length( ).
WRITE: 'Item count: ', lv_i.
CHECK lv_i IS NOT INITIAL.
lo_node = lo_nodes->get_item( index = 0 ).
CHECK lo_node IS NOT INITIAL.
lv_string = lo_node->get_value( ).
WRITE /: lv_string.
```

Comment: thank you! Will this work when I've imported the file and didn't implement it directly? The code is supposed to work for any file put in via a selection screen.

Comment: Yes, it works. There are better way to loading file to xml document rather than converting with SDIXML_XML_TO_DOM.